# How to set php cookie for a redirect

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

When people visit my site, I need them to click one of two states (NC or VA).  Depending on which state is clicked, it will redirect them to the appropriate page on my site.  After the cookie is set, I want them to visit the site and instead of asking the question again, it already knows to send them to the page (the state) they selected.  I know very little about php...just enough to be dangerous and any direction you can give me would be appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 2):

You can set the cookie as:

```
setcookie('state', $state, time() + (60 * 60 *24));
```

Assuming `$state` is either 'nc' or 'va', this will work:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['state']))
{
    if($_COOKIE['state'] == 'va')
        header('Location: va/index.php');
    else if($_COOKIE['state'] == 'nc')
        header('Location: vnc/index.php');
}
else
{
    // Make them choose again here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But how does the code for the cookie know which state they selected? i think that's where i get confused.

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="North Carolina" value="checkbox" id="state_nc" />
      North Carolina</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Virginia" value="checkbox" id="state_va" />
      Virginia</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    <br />
  </p>
</form>

Comment: You need to change the value of each checkbox to represent the value you need. And then you can access it through the $_POST array.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I'm going to work on it this afternoon and we'll see how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this php function [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

```
setcookie( "state", "VA", time()+3600 );
```

Then redirect using the location header.

```
header( "Location: /" );
```

Answer (score 0):

On the index page

```
<?php

if(isset($_COOKIE['state']))
{
   switch($_COOKIE['state'])
   {
      case "NC":
        header('location: www.url.com/site1/');
      break;

      case "VA":
        header('location: www.url.com/site2/');
      break;
   }

}
else
{
   //Display site options
}

?>
```

And on the individual sites (EG www.url.com/site1/):

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['state']))
{
  setcookie('state', "NC" ,time() + (86400 * 7)); //valid for 7 days
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you.  If I have two check boxes and they submit their state, how does my form and the cookie work together?

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="North Carolina" value="checkbox" id="state_nc" />
      North Carolina</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Virginia" value="checkbox" id="state_va" />
      Virginia</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    <br />
  </p>
</form>